# How to change Text color in Div without changing border color

Tags: html, css, colors

```
<div class = "signupsubmit">Continue</div>
<style>
.signupsubmit {
        line-height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 36px;
        top: 527px;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600;
        width: 137px;
        height: 30px;
        border-color: #00297A;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: #FFB630;
        text-indent: 30px;
        }
</style>
```

I am trying to change the text color to black but keep the border color the same so this is what I did

```
 <div class = "signupsubmit">Continue</div>
<style>
.signupsubmit {
        line-height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 36px;
        top: 527px;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600;
        width: 137px;
        height: 30px;
        border-color: #00297A;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: #FFB630;
        text-indent: 30px;
        color: white; <!-- NEW LINE OF CODE -->
        }
</style>
```

I did `color:white`, but it also changed the border color to white too. I want to keep the border color black.

Comment: @kannan: Not required. The shorthand `border` overwrites the `border-color` setting to the default value. All that is needed is for the `border-color` to be moved below the `border: 1px` or for `border: 1px` to be changed to `border-width: 1px`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me is combining the border properties into 1 line using the [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Border_Properties) syntax...

```css
.signupsubmit {
    line-height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36px;
    top: 527px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 137px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #00297A;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FFB630;
    text-indent: 30px;
    color: white; <!-- NEW LINE OF CODE -->
}
```

```html
<div class = "signupsubmit">Continue</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use a shorthand property, such as `border`, **all** the unspecified properties are set to their default (initial) value. In this case, the default `border-color` is `currentColor`, which picks up whatever the current color is--in this case `white`. You can solve this problem by either explicitly specifying the color in the `border` shorthand property specification, as suggested in other answers, or merely change `border: 1px;` to `border-width: 1px;`.

For information on how shorthand properties, work, see the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties):

> A value which is not specified is set to its initial value. That sounds anecdotal, but it really means that it **overrides** previously set values.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your `border` into one `border:1px solid #00297A;`

```css
.signupsubmit {
  line-height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 36px;
  top: 527px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 137px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border:1px solid #00297A;
  background-color: #FFB630;
  text-indent: 30px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="signupsubmit">Continue</div>
```

Comment: Don't know @torazaburo

Comment: It looks the exact same as my code but changes the result.